# World OF Warcraft in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, wine, games, playonlinux

I have tried launching 'The Blizzard Game Downloader', using `wine`, yet it does not get to the loading screen before it crashes, and ends with an error message.

Neither does trying to load the game through PlayOnLinux. I am an absoloute Ubuntu Noob also.

- Any help would be much appreciated. (Preferable Patch 5.4 support)

Answer (score 1):

have you tried the solution proposed on ubuntu's help site ?

here it is : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WorldofWarcraft

Answer (score 0):

well I was playing WOW on my 12.04 box and wine worked good for some reason when i right clicked the World of Warcraft Launcher.exe to use wine it would crash as well but if i right clicked it and clicked open with and then clicked rundll32 it would run the patcher/loader no problem but as a rule i normaly just right click the Wow.exe and open it with wine with no problems.

But I do have a problem with my computer shutting down when i am playing I think due to over heating possible as i am using an old acer aspire 7736z the only.

Ow btw you may have to modify the SET gxApi in your WTF.conf file in the WTF folder on the 6th line it calls for DX and i had to change mine to SET gxApi "OpenGL" to get it to run but then again like i said I am using an old POS computer you may be fine.

Joe